# Error while doing node package installation using any Package Manager

Tags: node.js, npm, memory-leaks, package.json

I've ever tried to do this kind of thing for a while. But it starts throwing me error since 2 days ago. I don't really know what happened. I'm using Windows 11.

At first, I was using `npm` and `pnpm`. After it always gives me error, I tried the `yarn`. It's just the same. I also tried to downgrade my nodeJS version to some of other version, but nothing helps.

Here some of Package Manager that I tried and the error it returns:

`npm i` returning error:

```
 WARN  GET http://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite error (ETIMEDOUT). Will retry in 10 seconds. 2 retries left.
 WARN  GET http://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite error (ETIMEDOUT). Will retry in 1 minute. 1 retries left.
 ERR_PNPM_META_FETCH_FAIL  GET http://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite failed, reason:
../../.pnpm-store/v3/tmp/dlx-6212        |   +1 +
../../.pnpm-store/v3/tmp/dlx-6212        | Progress: resolved 1, reused 0, downloaded 0, added 0
(node:6212) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite/-/create-vite-4.4.1.tgz failed, reason:
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\SalamP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pnpm\dist\pnpm.cjs:61908:18)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
../../.pnpm-store/v3/tmp/dlx-6212        | Progress: resolved 1, reused 0, downloaded 0, added 0
```

`yarn create vite` returning error:

```
yarn create v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
⠁ create-vite(node:22428) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
⡀ create-vite(node:22428) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
⠐ create-vite(node:22428) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
⠄ create-vite(node:22428) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
⠠ create-vite(node:22428) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/create-vite: ".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\SalamP\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/create for documentation about this command.
PS W:\Outbound\Code\Test PM>
```